# Interpolating periodic data in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I have a module that collects stats in an inconsistent time interval. Unfortunately, to use it nicely in a graph, I need the `x` values interpolated to a consistent interval.

Given the following `x`, `y` pairs, what's the most Pythonic way to do this?

```
(1, 23), (2, 42), (3.5, 89), (5, 73), (7, 54), (8, 41), (8.5, 37), (9, 23)
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: `y = mx + c`. You can "normalise" any line by first linearising it. Then, as it's a straight line it's easy to move down that line to the correct x / y value you need along the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1, 23), (2, 42), (3.5, 89), (5, 73), (7, 54), (8, 41), (8.5, 37), (9, 23)])

x = np.arange(1, 10) # target x values

b = zip(x, np.interp(x, a[:,0], a[:,1]))

# b == [(1, 23.0),
#       (2, 42.0),
#       (3, 73.333333333333329),
#       (4, 83.666666666666671),
#       (5, 73.0),
#       (6, 63.5),
#       (7, 54.0),
#       (8, 41.0),
#       (9, 23.0)]
```